# how to use grunt-usemin with font awesome

Tags: gruntjs, font-awesome, grunt-usemin

I am trying to use grunt-usemin to minify my css.  I am using Font Awesome like this within my index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

When I run usemin, I get all the styles combined.  However, when I try to use the minified version, the Font Awesome icons show up as unicode squares (not as the intended icons).

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I can include more information if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that font-awesome.min.css is referencing fonts in:

```
../font/
```

The key to fixing was to also copy the fonts folder out of the components/font-awesome/fonts folder to a fonts folder that is at the right relative path.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way would be to re-define the `$fa-font-path` in your `SCSS`/`LESS` file:

```css
$fa-font-path: '../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts' !default;
// $fa-font-path:        "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/fonts" !default; // for referencing Bootstrap CDN font files directly
```

Also Don't forget to `@import "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";` in your `main.scss`.